# Why this Ajax ResponseText is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

```
$("b_xml").onclick=function(){
        new Ajax.Request("books.php", {
            method:"GET",
            parameters: {category:getCheckedRadio(document.getElementsByName("category"))},
            onSuccess: showBooks_JSON,
            onFailure: ajaxFailed
        })
    }
```

When click button, new Ajax Request is created and call data from books.php.
so I use getElementByName to collect all named="category" radio button 
here is my html code

```
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="children" checked="checked"/> Children</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="computers" /> Computers</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="cooking" /> Cooking</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="finance" /> Finance</label>
```

and books.php

```
<?php
$BOOKS_FILE = "books.txt";

function filter_chars($str) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]*/", "", $str);
}

if (!isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) || $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "GET") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
    die("ERROR 400: Invalid request - This service accepts only GET requests.");
}

$category = "";
$delay = 0;

if (isset($_REQUEST["category"])) {
    $category = filter_chars($_REQUEST["category"]);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["delay"])) {
    $delay = max(0, min(60, (int) filter_chars($_REQUEST["delay"])));
}

if ($delay > 0) {
    sleep($delay);
}

if (!file_exists($BOOKS_FILE)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    die("ERROR 500: Server error - Unable to read input file: $BOOKS_FILE");
}

header("Content-type: application/xml");

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
print "<books>\n";


$lines = file($BOOKS_FILE);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    list($title, $author, $book_category, $year, $price) = explode("|", trim($lines[$i]));
    if ($book_category == $category) {
        print "\t<book category=\"$category\">\n";
        print "\t\t<title>$title</title>\n";
        print "\t\t<author>$author</author>\n";
        print "\t\t<year>$year</year>\n";
        print "\t\t<price>$price</price>\n";
        print "\t</book>\n";        
    }
}
print "</books>";
?>
```

I checked books.txt is not empty 
and when I click button, alert is work but It returns empty box.
What is problem?

Comment: the success function is called `showBooks_JSON` - but your PHP clearly responds with XML ... even without seeing `showBooks_JSON` function it's clear there's probable errors in your browser console that you haven't mentioned

Comment: But showBooks_XML and showBooks_JSON is completely same function. They return ajaxresponsetext likewise. I try run this after changing showBooks_JSON to showBooks_XML but It equally return empty value

Comment: you've not shown the function - it's probably doing something wrong

Comment: ```function showBooks_XML(ajax) {
 alert(ajax.responseText);
}

function showBooks_JSON(ajax) {
 alert(ajax.responseText);
}```This is my function. They are same

Comment: I guess step one would be narrow down the problem with some basic troubleshooting, which you appear not to have done. Look at the ajax request. Does the PHP return what you're expecting? If so, this is a Javascript problem. If not, it's a PHP problem.

Answer (score -1):

To return JSON from your books.php

```
<?
$BOOKS_FILE = "books.txt"; $BOOKS_XML = "";

function filter_chars($str) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]*/", "", $str);
}

if (!isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) || $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "GET") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
    die("ERROR 400: Invalid request - This service accepts only GET requests.");
}

$category = "";
$delay = 0;

if (isset($_REQUEST["category"])) {
    $category = filter_chars($_REQUEST["category"]);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["delay"])) {
    $delay = max(0, min(60, (int) filter_chars($_REQUEST["delay"])));
}

if ($delay > 0) {
    sleep($delay);
}

if (!file_exists($BOOKS_FILE)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    die("ERROR 500: Server error - Unable to read input file: $BOOKS_FILE");
}

header("Content-type: application/xml");

$BOOKS_XML += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$BOOKS_XML += "<books>\n";


$lines = file($BOOKS_FILE);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    list($title, $author, $book_category, $year, $price) = explode("|", trim($lines[$i]));
    if ($book_category == $category) {
        $BOOKS_XML += "\t<book category=\"$category\">\n";
        $BOOKS_XML += "\t\t<title>$title</title>\n";
        $BOOKS_XML += "\t\t<author>$author</author>\n";
        $BOOKS_XML += "\t\t<year>$year</year>\n";
        $BOOKS_XML += "\t\t<price>$price</price>\n";
        $BOOKS_XML += "\t</book>\n";        
    }
}
$BOOKS_XML += "</books>";

$JSON = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($BOOKS_XML));
echo $JSON;
?>
```

Comment: sorry I does not work. It equally return empty value.